# placement of [something] in [five dollars] and [twenty dollars]

Tags: word-usage

If you bought something between $5 and $6 (that means, $5.10, $5.20, ... , $5.80, $5.90), would you say

(1a) It cost five dollars something.

(1b) It cost five something dollars.

If you bought something between $20 and $30 (that means, $21, $22, ... ,$28, $29), would you say

(2a) It cost twenty dollars something.

(2b) It cost twenty something dollars.

Answer (score 1):

Since we say "five dollars forty" for $5.40, I would go with five dollars something. If heard "five something dollars" I would expect it to mean the same thing.

I would go with "twenty-something dollars" as I would expect "twenty dollars something" to be less than $21.